# PDFpages isn't importing files with accented characters

Tags: pdfpages

I'm currently trying to include a pdf file with pdfpages, but the file has some accented characters.

Let's say for example the filename is "éte.pdf". Both tries below give an error

```
\includepdf{"éte.pdf"}
\includepdf{"\'{e}te.pdf"}
```

The only way I found to go around this is to rename the file to remove the accent, but the file is generated autamatically by another software which I can't change, so I would have to rename everytime I created the pdf.

Using `includegraphics{éte.pdf}` works fine but it wont make the entire page.

Is there a way to make pdfpages accept the original file name?

Comment: Please post a full MWE, together with any error messages you are receiving. Accented characters work just fine for me.

Comment: Are you using PDFLaTeX/XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX? Are you on Windows/Mac/something else?

Comment: Also, you probably should not be including the quotes `"`...?

Comment: @user202729 thanks for that link. It worked!